# How to consume CSV file in Angular 2(TypeScript)

Tags: angular

I want to upload an excel file and the data in Excel file should be displayed in my Angular 2 project.
Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full tutorial to read a  .csv file in Angular 2  http://javabypatel.blogspot.in/2017/07/read-csv-file-in-angular2.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [papa parse](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse).

It can convert JSON to CSV and vice versa.